# Roots of an equation with normally distributed variable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, normal-distribution, roots

Consider the following equation:

$p\left(1-\int _{\mu}^{x} f(y)dy\right) \left[p\left(1-\int _{\mu}^{x} f(y)dy\right)+(1-p)q \right]-xf(x)p(1-p)q=0$,

where $p,q \in [0,1]$, $f(\cdot)$ is the probability density of the normal distribution and $\mu$ is the mean of the variable $x$.

**My question is: is there any root $x^{\ast}$ in the above equation? How can I prove the existence?**

What I have already known:

(i) If $\mu = \frac{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}(p+(1-p)q)}{(1-p)q}$, then $x^{\ast}=\mu$ is a root, where $\sigma$ is the variance of $x$. But I want to find a $x^{\ast}$ for an arbitrary $\mu >0$.

(ii) For $x$ large or lower enough, the expression is positive. However, I cannot prove that it is negative for some other $x$. So it is impossible for me to use some result like the Mean Value Theorem.

(iii) A necessary condition for the existence is $x>0$, independent of the value of the mean.

What I expect: in the general case, there are at least two roots, one higher than $\mu$ and another lower. It would be great if I could prove that!

Thank you!

Comment: If $\mu^*$ is the $\mu$ in your point (i) then numerically it seems like for $\mu^* - \epsilon < \mu < \mu^*$ there are two solutions $x$ which are $< \mu$ and for $\mu > \mu^*$ there is one solution $x > \mu$ and one $x < \mu$. Further there seems to be a $\mu^{**}$ with $0 < \mu^{**} < \mu^*$ such that if $\mu < \mu^{**}$ then there are no solutions. [Here is a plot of the set of solutions in the $\mu,x$-plane](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CnBbY.png) with $p=3/5$, $q=2/3$, and $\sigma = 1$. The point $x=\mu=\mu^*$ is shown in black, and the line $\mu = x$ is shown in orange.